# Cannot Find name error coming in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a component called `customComponent`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { appService } from './app.service'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-root',
  template: `<h1>how</h1>
    <ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes"><li>{{hero}}</li></ul>`,
})
export class CustomComponent {
    heroes = ['first','second','third'];
   //heroes;

   value: string = ""; 
 // constructor(appService: appService) { }  

   /* ngOnInit(): void { 
      this.value = this._appService.getApp(); 
   } */

}
```

In `appService` i have

```
import { 
   Injectable 
} from '@angular/core';  

@Injectable()
export class appService {  
   getApp(): string { 
      return "Hello world"; 
   } 
}
```

In `app.module.ts` i am importing the app service

```
import { appService } from './app.service'; 


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,CustomComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule
   // appService
  ],  
  providers: [appService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now I am getting an error

> cannot find name appService in custom Component line number 15

How can I solve this?

Comment: You had commented reference to service ? Any special reason?

Comment: why r u calling it `_appService` in ngOnInit? why not `appService` ? and why you deleted the constructor that inject the service?

Comment: another thing is that the `*ngFor` statement should be on the `<li>` and not on the `<ul>`

Comment: @The dictator i have added in app.module.ts

Answer (score 9):

In CustomComponent file import:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

Then use it in constructor for DI:

```
constructor(@Inject(appService) private appService) { }
```

After this make sure you uncomment appService in providers of your module.

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  RouterModule,
  appService
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code block

```
export class CustomComponent {
    heroes = ['first','second','third'];
   //heroes;

   value: string = ""; 
   constructor(private appService: appService) { }  

   ngOnInit(): void { 
      this.value = this.appService.getApp(); 
   }

}
```

Issues :

You are calling this._appService.getApp();

1. You haven't define _appService.
2. Haven't DI for appService.